# AzureAD : Could not validate this directory for deletion

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to delete the Azure AD directory. I have:
1>Deleted all the applications.
2>Deleted all the users (Except the microsoft account that created the directory)
3>No Subscription associated with this directory.

When i was trying to delete the directory using Azure portal, i was getting error

> Directory has one or more applications that were added by a user or
>   administrator.

so i followed the article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgolpe/2015/04/30/walkthrough-of-deleting-an-azure-ad-tenant/) to delete the directory using powershell

and now when i try to delete directory using Azure Portal i get error

> Could not validate this directory for deletion

[image]

Comment: I have same issue. Most of AD features are inaccessible and keep receiving messages like "We are still configuring this portion of your directory. Try again in a few minutes."

Comment: @AliMalekpour we are not using azure anymore. It was pain to configure and also to get help from MS. We wasted all most 2 months. Now we hosted our own authentication using identityserver.